# Android: Sqlite DB Upgrade openOrCreateDatabase

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite

Have used openOrCreateDatabase to create a SQLiteDatabase associated with my application package.[Wat does setVersion api do?](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#setVersion%28int%29)
Now my DB is getting upgraded on newer version of my app.Is there any upgrade callback? OR we need to use SQLiteOpenHelper to get upgrade callback?

Comment: Have you heard about [`onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper.html#onUpgrade%28android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase,%20int,%20int%29)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`openOrCreateDatabase()` just opens the database file, creating a new one if one doesn't already exist.

There's no versioning involved, and no schema creation / upgrade callbacks. `SQLiteOpenHelper` is an easy way to provide such functionality.

To learn how `SQLiteOpenHelper` does the versioning and invokes callbacks, see the [source](http://androidxref.com/4.4.2_r1/xref/frameworks/base/core/java/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper.java#192).

Comment: @Iaalto As i thought, so u mean we need to go with SQLiteOpenHelper approach.?Thanks.

Comment: If you don't want to write your own versioning, yes.

Comment: "you don't want to write your own versioning" you meant "you want to write your own versioning"? Can you elaborate here.

Comment: "versioning", not "visioning". See the linked platform source code.

Comment: just edited, let me check that.Using SQLiteOpenHelper i will be having control on verisoning right.On newer version i will be getting a onUpgrade Call back.